# Hit point with projectile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the correct angle my cannon needs to be at to hit a target point. The code below always sets the angle to 90 degrees. I am using c# and Unity. Any suggestions for what I am doing wrong?

```
        double x = -(source.x - position.x);
        double y = (source.y - position.y);
        double v = 500; //m/s
        double g = Physics2D.gravity.y;
        double sqrt = (v * v * v * v) - (g * (g * (x * x) + 2 * y * (v * v)));
        sqrt = Math.Sqrt(sqrt);
        double angleInRadians = Math.Atan2(((v * v) + sqrt), (g * x));

        double degrees = angleInRadians * Mathf.Rad2Deg; //This is always 90
        Vector3 angle = new Vector3(0,180,(float)degrees);

        _cannon.transform.localEulerAngles = angle;
```

Comment: There's really no need to use doubles here, you can stick with float just for simplicity (and use `Mathf.Sqrt()`). What's the value of `g`?

Comment: g is -9.81. I'll convert to floats, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution to this problem, here is the solution:

```
    private float _power = 0.5f;
    private float _mass = 0.5f;
    private float _powerMultiplier = 2000f; //Adjust this to lower or raise max reach

    public void Update()
    {
        Vector2 target = Global.Player1.CastlePosition;
        Vector2 source = transform.position;

        if (!CanHitCoordinate(source, target))
        {
            _power += 0.01f;
            return;
        }

        float angle = CalculateAngleToHitCoordinate(source, target);
        Vector3 newAngle = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
        _cannon.transform.localEulerAngles = newAngle;
    }

    private float CalculateAngleToHitCoordinate(Vector2 source, Vector2 target) 
    {
        float power = _power * _powerMultiplier;
        float x = -(source.x - target.x);
        float y = -(source.y - target.y);


        float v = (power / mass) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        float g = -Physics2D.gravity.y; //Needs to be positive

        float sqrt = (v * v * v * v) - (g * (g * (x * x) + 2 * y * (v * v)));
        sqrt = Mathf.Sqrt(sqrt);

        double angleInRadians = Math.Atan((v * v + sqrt) / (g * x));
        return (float)angleInRadians * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    }

    private float CalculateDelta(Vector2 source, Vector2 target)
    {
        float power = _power * _powerMultiplier;
        float x = (source.x - target.x);
        float y = -(source.y - target.y);


        float v = (power / 0.5f) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        float g = -Physics2D.gravity.y;
        return (v * v * v * v) - (g * (g * (x * x) + 2 * y * (v * v)));
    }

    public bool CanHitCoordinate(Vector2 source, Vector2 target)
    {
        return CalculateDelta(source, target) >= 0;
    }
```

This is for a source shooting towards a target to the right of it. To shoot towards a target on the left simply make these two changes to the above code:

```
float x = (source.x - target.x); //Remove "-"
Vector3 newAngle = new Vector3(0, 180, angle); //Point towards the left
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [`Mathf.Atan2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.90).aspx) definition:

> If y is positive and x is 0, θ = π/2.

`x` is the second parameter, so your `g * x` results in 0. Basic math tells us that this can be if any or all of the operands are equal to 0.

So, in essence, either:

- `-(source.x - position.x)` or
- `Physics2D.gravity.y`

is equal to 0. I'd guess gravity's `y` value is the culprit here.

Comment: `-(source.x - position.x) = -20.999755859375` and  `Physics2D.gravity.y = -9.8100004196167` Tested right before my equation. y can often be negative, does that matter?